# syslog-ng tail file missing last line

Tags: syslog-ng

I'm using wildcard-file source on a number of logs, some of which are quite slow moving, which means I've noticed the last line of the log file is never sent to the destination in a timely manner.  Sometimes there will be 50 minutes between logs being written locally, and in all that time the last line of the log file is never sent to the destination.

The destination is elasticsearch-http, I've tried setting batch-timeout() to 2 seconds or something low in the destination block, and added follow-freq(1) to the source config to no avail.

Is it something to do with the fact the last line doesn't have a newline and therefore syslog-ng  won't ever read it until newer lines are written? If so, how could one flush this last line to the destination?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the file has to be terminated with a newline character in order to be considered as complete.

In case you have no control over the format of the logs processed by syslog-ng, you could try using `multi-line-mode()` and `multi-line-timeout()` as a workaround to flush the last incomplete line after a certain timeout.